# How to add style to append function

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to change the color of font & make the content align='center' for the content in the append function.The content is value fetched from the db & is in the array. 
Please Help!

```
currentrow
    .find('td')
    .next()
    .css('background-color', 'red')
    .addClass('active')
    .attr("title", namearray[j])
    .append(namearray[j]);
```

Comment: `for the content in the append function` ?? whats the content in that function?

Comment: It is the value fetched from the db & present in array i.e namearray[j]

Comment: whats inside `namearray[j]`? a html element or a plain string or a html string?

Comment: Plain String i.e username like ankit

Comment: also you cant apply style to append function. you can only apply to a DOM element. `currentrow.find('td').next().css('background-color','red').addClass('active')` will apply what you want

Comment: Sir that is giving the background color red to my row but .attr("title",namearray[j]) fetches value from the db & i want the same i.e .append(namearray[j]) text to be in white font-color & aligned center which is left at present

Comment: can you recreate the problem in a fiddle and share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go,,

http://codepen.io/mkdizajn/pen/pJVWem?editors=101

hope that solves it..

the key part I think is this:

```
$('table tr')
    .eq(1) // find second row for ex..
    .find('td').eq(1) // find second cell for ex..
    .css('background-color', 'red') // give it some color
    .addClass('active').attr("title", 'mirko').css('text-align', 'center') // center position
;
```

hth

Comment: Thanks for the code but Sir i want it for .append()

Comment: you can also use append to that I added that also :)

Comment: Got the desired result as per my requirement. Thank You for the help !